# Passing array of vector in pyOpencl

Tags: numpy, opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to pass numpy array to kernel as array of opencl vector.
(numpy array of np.int32 -> int3*)
But result seems weired.
It will be very appreciated if someone explain why does it happened.

Thanks in advance.

The source code :

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

platforms = cl.get_platforms()
ctx = cl.Context(dev_type=cl.device_type.GPU, properties=[(cl.context_properties.PLATFORM, platforms[0])])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

rowcnt = 3
ipt = np.linspace(1, rowcnt * 3, num=rowcnt * 3, dtype=np.int32)
rst = np.ones((rowcnt * 3), dtype=np.int32)

mf = cl.mem_flags
iptbuf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=ipt)
rstbuf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, rst.nbytes)

src = '''
__kernel void test(__global int3* ipt, __global int* rst) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    rst[idx * 3] = ipt[idx].x;
    rst[idx * 3 + 1] = ipt[idx].y;
    rst[idx * 3 + 2] = ipt[idx].z;
}
'''

prg = cl.Program(ctx, src).build()
prg.test(queue, (rowcnt, ), None, iptbuf, rstbuf)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, rst, rstbuf)

print ipt
print rst
```

Expected output :

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Result output :

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 5 6 7 9 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`int3` (and other type3 types) behave as `int4` (and other type4 types) for the purposes of size and alignment. So you need to take this into account in your example. You can verify this quickly by modifying your example to use `int4` and update everything else related accordingly.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

platforms = cl.get_platforms()
ctx = cl.Context(dev_type=cl.device_type.GPU, properties=[(cl.context_properties.PLATFORM, platforms[0])])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

rowcnt = 4
ipt = np.linspace(1, rowcnt * 4, num=rowcnt * 4, dtype=np.int32)
rst = np.ones((rowcnt * 4), dtype=np.int32)

mf = cl.mem_flags
iptbuf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=ipt)
rstbuf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, rst.nbytes)

src = '''
__kernel void test(__global int4* ipt, __global int* rst) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    rst[idx * 4] = ipt[idx].x;
    rst[idx * 4 + 1] = ipt[idx].y;
    rst[idx * 4 + 2] = ipt[idx].z;
    rst[idx * 4 + 3] = ipt[idx].w;
}
'''

prg = cl.Program(ctx, src).build()
prg.test(queue, (rowcnt, ), None, iptbuf, rstbuf)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, rst, rstbuf)

print ipt
print rst
```

Output:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```